# What is difference between centos 6.6 and centos 6.6 minimal server as i want to install it in vmware workstation?

Tags: linux, centos, cloud, eucalyptus, qt-faststart

I have a windows laptop with 8 gb ram and i want to try out creating a private cloud using eucalyptus without deleting windows os of my laptop.So i installed vmware and now i want to install centos-6.6 minimal server in vmware inorder to install eucalyptus private cloud in centos using Fast start.
Fast-start
in this site.
[a link](https://www.eucalyptus.com/eucalyptus-cloud/get-started)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A minimal install will land you with a bare-metal installation without a GUI.
You will have to manually install and run the GUI.

Plus side is, faster installation & smaller size.

Downside.. Well, if working on command line full time doesn't suit you, that's a con.

Answer (score -1):

There is no difference between minimal server and a minimal centos.Both are same